# HTML canvas performance when drawing partially beyond screen

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

It's my understanding that with the HTML canvas, bigger shapes actually take more time. So if you draw a 100x100 square vs a 1000x1000 square, you can expect the 100x100 to be faster.

Does this also hold for shapes that are bigger, but partially off-screen?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
a 500x500 canvas
0,0 --------
|          |
|-------500,500
```

Now if I draw at (0,250) a rectangle of width 1000000, it'll stretch across the entire canvas horizontally. But if I draw a rectangle of width 500 at (250, 250), it'll look the same to the end user since it also stretches across the full canvas width.

Do these two rectangles render at the same speed, since the  actual portion visible to the user is the same? Or does the extra width, even though it's not actually invisible, actually impact the performance?

Comment: Run a benchmark and see. Then share the fiddle, and results here.

Comment: To be honest I was just being lazy and hoping someone else already knew haha, but yeah I'll probably do that and post results here in a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't entirely a complete answer, but I did some experimentation and my results only confused me more, although I don't see anything obvious that could explain my results.

```
587.2700000000001ms elapsed - test for size 500
108.55999999999995ms elapsed - test for size 50
237.32500000000005ms elapsed - test for size 250
476.45500000000015ms elapsed - test for size 500
500.65499999999975ms elapsed - test for size 1000
478.5500000000002ms elapsed - test for size 2000
58.24000000000024ms elapsed - test for size 5000
58.460000000000036ms elapsed - test for size 10000
60.82999999999993ms elapsed - test for size 25000
```

Thinking these results to be strange, I tried another set of inputs to even stranger results

```
72.76499999999987ms elapsed - test for size 500000
61.690000000000055ms elapsed - test for size 10000
58.47499999999991ms elapsed - test for size 5000
620.9050000000002ms elapsed - test for size 1000
475.0450000000001ms elapsed - test for size 500
379.0250000000001ms elapsed - test for size 400
281.7850000000003ms elapsed - test for size 300
186.54500000000007ms elapsed - test for size 200
120.51500000000033ms elapsed - test for size 100
59.210000000000036ms elapsed - test for size 50000
58.220000000000255ms elapsed - test for size 500000
```

These tests were conducted in Firefox, and the results seem to render correctly even for the weirdly fast sizes.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vrn7xrrj/1/

I would greatly appreciate any input on this..